# Create Web Sessions

Tags: r

I know that Randy has a great post on [Sessonizing Log Data](http://randyzwitch.com/sessionizing-log-data-dplyr-r-window-functions/), but I am struggling with tweaking the idea to generate session ids based on 30-minute inactivity windows.

Here is what I am hoping to generate in `R`, and preferably, with `dplyr`.  I am looking to calculate the `session_id` variable shown below.

```
   dim_user_id       activity_date session_id
1      2665871 2014-12-31 19:00:08         1
2      2665871 2014-12-31 19:00:45         1
3      2665871 2014-12-31 19:01:01         1
4      2665877 2014-12-31 19:00:08         2
5      2665877 2014-12-31 19:00:33         2
6      2666612 2014-12-31 19:08:19         3
7      2666612 2014-12-31 19:08:32         3
8      2666612 2014-12-31 19:09:04         3
9      2666626 2014-12-31 19:00:25         4
10     2666627 2014-12-31 19:04:39         5
```

The code that I was trying to use was:

```
user_activity$sid = 1:nrow(user_activity)
user_activity$session_id = NA
# startTime = Sys.time()
user_activity = user_activity %>% 
  group_by(dim_user_id) %>% 
  arrange(activity_date) %>% 
  transform(lag_seconds = ifelse(lag(dim_user_id) == dim_user_id, 
                                 as.numeric(activity_date - lag(activity_date)), 
                                 9999)) %>% 
  mutate(session_id = ifelse(is.na(lag_seconds) | lag_seconds >= 1801, sid, lag(session_id)))
```

but the issue that I am running into is that I do not believe the value is being set row-wise.  I did explore the `rowwwise` function in `dplyr`, but I am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you are looking for `group_indices` which you can use as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(session_id = group_indices_(df, .dots="dim_user_id"))
```

EDIT: 
As your sample data does not provide a case where one user has multiple sessions with 30+ time diff i used this altered data set:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="dim_user_id date  time
2665871 2014-12-31 19:00:08
2665871 2014-12-31 19:00:45
2665871 2014-12-31 19:01:01
2665877 2014-12-31 19:00:08
2665877 2014-12-31 19:00:33
2666612 2014-12-31 19:08:19
2666612 2014-12-31 19:38:32
2666612 2014-12-31 19:39:04
2666626 2014-12-31 19:00:25
2666627 2014-12-31 19:04:39")

df$activity_date <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, df$time))
df$date <- NULL
df$time <- NULL
```

So user #2666612 has a 30+ min lag. The following code calculates your session_id's step by step. I am sure it could be shortened but this is for clarification.

```
require(dplyr)
cuttoff <- 30*60 # 30 min times 60 seconds.
df %>% 
  # group by user_id
  group_by(dim_user_id) %>% 
  # Difference in seconds within a given user
  mutate(time_diff = c(0, diff(activity_date))) %>%
  # If the difference is >cutoff start new session
  mutate(session_num = cumsum(time_diff>cuttoff)) %>% 
  # ungroup to set group_indices data-wide instead of groupwide
  ungroup() %>% 
  # calculate group_indices based in user_id and session_num
  mutate(session_id = group_indices_(., .dots=c("dim_user_id", "session_num")))
```

Which results in:

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 5]

   dim_user_id       activity_date time_diff session_num session_id
         (int)              (time)     (dbl)       (int)      (int)
1      2665871 2014-12-31 19:00:08         0           0          1
2      2665871 2014-12-31 19:00:45        37           0          1
3      2665871 2014-12-31 19:01:01        16           0          1
4      2665877 2014-12-31 19:00:08         0           0          2
5      2665877 2014-12-31 19:00:33        25           0          2
6      2666612 2014-12-31 19:08:19         0           0          3
7      2666612 2014-12-31 19:38:32      1813           1          4
8      2666612 2014-12-31 19:39:04        32           1          4
9      2666626 2014-12-31 19:00:25         0           0          5
10     2666627 2014-12-31 19:04:39         0           0          6
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `group_indices`, that is fantastic.  The only thing that I need to do is create a new session if the user's next activity date occurs 30+ minutes later, if ever.  I stumbled across this example, but I might need to tweak it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413514/creating-a-session-visit-id-in-r?rq=1

Comment: @Btibert3 please see my edit. And next time please add those edge-cases to your sample data-set

Comment: That is fantastic, thanks.  One question.  I have seen `cumsum` pop up in the various solutions.  Even seeing it above, what is it doing?

Comment: Have a look at `?cumsum`. `cumsum(1:3)` gives you `1, 3, 6` so it sums up all the previous numbers. Here is sums over a logical `time_diff>cuttoff` so it  sums over `0=FALSE` and `1=TRUE`'s. So it increases by 1 each time `difftime` is bigger than `cuttoff`